# Web Api Core 2 distinguishing GETs

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-core-2.0

Why can't Web API Core 2 tell these apart?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values?name=dave
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get(string name)
    {
        return $"name is {name}";
    }
```

Here's what happens -

Both `http://localhost:65528/api/values` and `http://localhost:65528/api/values?name=dave` cause the first `Get()` method to execute.

This exact code works fine in Web Api 2.

I [know](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/07/net-core-web-api-routing/) [multiple](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/08/net-core-multiple-get-methods-with-the-action-method-selector-attribute/) ways of getting around this, but I don't know *why* it happens.

Can someone explain why this has changed?

Comment: I don't think query strings are used for routes.

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can even compile your code in `ASP.NET Core Mvc 2.0` since you have 2 actions mapped to same route `[HttGet] api/values`:

```
AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched.
```

Remember, `ASP.NET Web API` uses the HTTP verb as part of the request to figure which action to call. Although it uses conventional routing (you name your actions Get, Post, Put and Delete, etc) if you don't have route attribute specify, I would highly recommend to always use routing attribute to annotate your controllers and actions.

### Api Design time

Now it's up to you to design the route, as a developer. Remember the route is supposed to be a `Uri` that can identify a resource / resources.

- Use the name as identifier along with the route

  ```cs
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class CustomersController : Controller
  {
      // api/customers
      [HttpGet]
      public IActionResult Get()
      {
         ...
      }

      // api/customers/dave
      [HttpGet("{name:alpha}")]     // constraint as a string 
      public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
      {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```
- Use the name as filter, against the resource collection

  ```cs
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class CustomersController : Controller
  {
      // api/customers
      // api/customers?name=dave
      [HttpGet]
      public IActionResult Get(string name)
      {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

## To confuse you more

`api/customers/dave` will still execute `GetById` first!

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Both methods `GetByName` and `GetById` are potential candidates but MVC picks `GetById` method first because MVC compares the method/template name `{name}` and `{id}` through case-insensitive string comparison, and `i` comes before `n`.

That's when you want to put **constraints**.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        ...
    }

    // api/customers/dave
    [HttpGet("{name:alpha}")]
    public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
    {
        ...
    }

    // api/customers/3
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also specify the **Ordering** too!

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        ...
    }

    // api/customers/portland
    [HttpGet("{city:alpha}", Order = 2)]
    public IActionResult GetByCity(string city)
    {
        ...
    }

    // api/customers/dave
    [HttpGet("{name:alpha}", Order = 1)]
    public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
    {
        ...
    }

    // api/customers/3
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Without the `Order`, the method `GetByCity` will be in favor than `GetByName` because character c of `{city}` comes before the character n of `{name}`. But if you specify the order, MVC will pick the action based on the `Order`.

Sigh the post is too long....

Comment: For the record, one of the catch-22's of attribute routing is the fact that in routing order is a significant design factor and .NET attributes order is undefined by default. This means you always have to be aware that if you have similar routes they need to be ordered (or constrained). Convention-based routing typically requires less configuration, is more extensible and powerful, and specifying the order is as simple as declaring them in the right order.

Comment: Thanks David, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Because in your case the best match in the route pipeline is the default httpget attribute (the one that get all). The query is a regular string so if you don't ask what you want from the query the best match is still the one that get all.

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get([FromQuery]string name)
{
    return $"name is {name}";
}
```

The [FromQuery] is pointing to the key "name" in the query string to get the value.
Your should read [Routing in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)