# JSON Patch HTTP request from client to API (published on AWS) returns "StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed'"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ecs, http-patch

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API published to Amazon ECS using AWS Fargate with working PATCH request that I have successfully tested using POSTMAN. Now I am trying to make that request in the client side application by following [this](https://github.com/KevinDockx/JsonPatch#:%7E:text=Here%27s%20how%20to,support%20is%20planned.).

What I have on client side is this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Patch(int companyId, string description)
{
    JsonPatchDocument<CompanyInfo> patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument<CompanyInfo>();
    patchDoc.Replace(e => e.Description, description);

    var jsonSerializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc);
    Debug.WriteLine(jsonSerializeObject);

    var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, "api/CompanyInfo/" + companyId)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(jsonSerializeObject, Encoding.Unicode, "application/json")
    };


    response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    Debug.WriteLine(response);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

This is what I get in my response:

```
StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Sat, 26 Nov 2022 06:06:08 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Server: Kestrel
  Content-Length: 0
  Allow: GET, PUT
}
```

As previously mentioned I have already confirmed the following json patch document using POSTMAN:

```
[
    {
        "value":"some text value",
        "path":"/Description",
        "op":"replace"
    }
]
```

The API:

```
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<ActionResult> PartiallyUpdateCompanyInfo(int companyId, JsonPatchDocument<CompanyInfoForPatchDto> patchDocument)
{
    var companyEntity = await _moviePlanetRepository.GetCompanyById(companyId, false);
    if (companyEntity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var companyToPatch = _mapper.Map<CompanyInfoForPatchDto>(companyEntity);

    patchDocument.ApplyTo(companyToPatch, ModelState);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (!TryValidateModel(companyToPatch))
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _mapper.Map(companyToPatch, companyEntity);
    await _moviePlanetRepository.Save();

    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: [This helped.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582449/http-verbs-put-and-delete-405-method-not-allowed-how-to-allow#:~:text=It%20wasn%27t%20sufficient%20to%20provide%20the%20above%20attributes%20to%20the%20methods.%20It%20was%20required%20to%20provide%20the%20methods%27%20address%20(and%20query%20string%2C%20resp.)%20parameters%20for%20these%20attributes%20(%5BHttpPut(%22%7Bid%7D%22)%5D%2C%20%5BHttpDelete(%22%7Bid%7D%22)%5D)%2C%20too.%20(This%20is%20particular%20to%20ASP.NET%20Core.))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to specify that the `companyId` was a required for the Route.
From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56617762/14503866)

> It wasn't sufficient to provide the above attributes to the methods.
> It was required to provide the methods' address (and query string,
> resp.) parameters for these attributes ([HttpPut("{id}")],
> [HttpDelete("{id}")]), too. (This is particular to ASP.NET Core.)

```
[Route("{companyId:int}")]
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<ActionResult> PartiallyUpdateCompanyInfo(int companyId, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<CompanyInfoForPatchDto> patchDocument)
{
    var companyEntity = await _moviePlanetRepository.GetCompanyById(companyId, false);
    if (companyEntity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var companyToPatch = _mapper.Map<CompanyInfoForPatchDto>(companyEntity);

    patchDocument.ApplyTo(companyToPatch, ModelState);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (!TryValidateModel(companyToPatch))
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _mapper.Map(companyToPatch, companyEntity);
    await _moviePlanetRepository.Save();

    return NoContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add [FromBody] attribute

```
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<ActionResult> PartiallyUpdateCompanyInfo(int companyId, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<CompanyInfoForPatchDto> patchDocument)
{
    var companyEntity = await _moviePlanetRepository.GetCompanyById(companyId, false);
    if (companyEntity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var companyToPatch = _mapper.Map<CompanyInfoForPatchDto>(companyEntity);

    patchDocument.ApplyTo(companyToPatch, ModelState);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (!TryValidateModel(companyToPatch))
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _mapper.Map(companyToPatch, companyEntity);
    await _moviePlanetRepository.Save();

    return NoContent();
}
```